# Cookie Decryption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, encryption

I have a strange problem; i can't decrypt a cookie value. I'm encrypting it with machine Key:

Web config :

```
  <machineKey decryptionKey="9931B3DF5DAD70FC6696E7F882AC2F51E4D78A72E3A7A2D0" validationKey="3471B0113B1F47164560DAC7AC89694A548B707A332F2BFAF80CBC5F4536217B9B1124F11A13B4E5E02D9EB976205708D9CF2E96F55845B16C4B1EFD8CE1BFAC" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Encryption :

```
   private string Protect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;

        byte[] stream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] encodedValue = MachineKey.Protect(stream, purpose);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encodedValue);
    }
```

Decryption :

```
 private string Unprotect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;
        byte[] stream = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, purpose);  // Here i have error
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedValue);
    }
```

From what i read this is related to the machine key but I'm defining this section in the application so i don't really understand where the problem is.

Error :

[image]

Comment: have you tried clearing your cookies and re-testing? I've had similar issues before when the browser had an old cookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation process is SHA1.

`Hashing` cannot be reversed(decrypted) back. (not at least for a forseeable future). If you need just encryption and decryption, then use an encryption and not `Hash` methods. `Hash` methods are for passwords, so you don't decrypt them back.

Change the `validation` process to `AES` for your machinekey tag in `web` config.

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="9931B3DF5DAD70FC6696E7F882AC2F51E4D78A72E3A7A2D0" validationKey="3471B0113B1F47164560DAC7AC89694A548B707A332F2BFAF80CBC5F4536217B9B1124F11A13B4E5E02D9EB976205708D9CF2E96F55845B16C4B1EFD8CE1BFAC" validation="AES" decryption="AES" />
```